# JSON.parse - Unexpcted token error

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert below string into JSON object -

```
var objString = "{ a:10, b:15 }";
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(objString);
```

I get below error -

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Any idea, how can I convert the string into an object?

Comment: Often useful to run your JSON through a JSON format checker to track down problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is invalid.

```
'{ a:10, b:15 }'
```

Your values are valid but your properties need to be in quotes like this:

```
'{ "a":10, "b":15 }'
```

Value datatypes can include:

- Number
- String
- Boolean
- Array
- Object
- null

Try this:

```
var objString = '{ "a":10, "b":15 }';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(objString);
```

More information here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm

Comment: Might be useful to explain _why_ it's invalid.

Comment: @loan.burger - I know, it's too late a reply. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

**Try this:**

```
var objString = '{ "a":10, "b":15 }';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(objString);
```

Comment: No. The JSON the OP had was invalid as shown in your example.

Comment: @Andy, What are you trying to convey

Comment: You say: "I think data you are trying to convert into JSON is already in JSON". This is incorrect. The OP isn't trying to convert _anything_ to JSON. They are trying to convert _from_ JSON to a JS object but can't because the JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

use " " inside ' ' , Then it will work.

```js
var objString = '{"a":"10", "b":"15" }';

//console.log(objString);

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(objString);

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```